# Chrome console - reload in loop

Tags: javascript, console.log

I need to check my visitor tracker so I entered this in the chrome console with the setting set to preserve the log:

```
i = 0; 
while (i<4) 
{ 
    location.reload();
    window.alert(i);
    i++;
}
```

The alert box pops pops up 4 times with the values ( 0, 1, 2, 3) and I also get the result:

> 3
>
> Navigated to "url of website"

The result and the alert box show that the code runs till the end but why does the page reload only once?

Please don't be harsh.

Comment: Ain't this about java behaviour flow. The loop runs but all the reload get queued up and after the loop, it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reload your page, all javascript code that you have written is lost. In your code, the `location.reload()` function is executed before `alert()`, but I suspect because it takes time for the `location.reload()` function to fully execute, it still has plenty time executing the `alert()` function, and also all the other iterations aswell, which leads to the while loop to finish before the page has reloaded.

`location.reload()` probably falls under the category of asynchronous functions, which means the function starts executing and keeps running in the background. All code that follows a asynchronous function is immediately executed, regardless of whether the asynchronous function has finished by then or not.

If you want to keep track of the visitor count, make use of some php and save the data in a database.

UPDATE:
Put this code into a .html file and open it. Reload it as many times as you wish, and check the `currentClicks` variable in your console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<script>
var currentClicks = localStorage.getItem("clickCount");
currentClicks++;
localStorage.setItem("clickCount", currentClicks);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably. All the alerts happen before the reload. Is there some way of storing the requests in local or session storage?

Comment: I think one could make use of localStorage and sessionStorage for such matters. But the problem is that those things just store data. To my knowledge, they don't execute data on page reload.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `location.reload()` sets up a request to reload the page, but one that does not take place immediately. It's probably waiting for the current code to finish running, and is then dispatched later. After it's dispatched once, the rest of the pending reloads are lost.

Comment: Probably. All the alerts happen before the reload. Is there some way of storing the requests in local or session storage?

Comment: You can store data, but I don't think you can store requests to execute code.

Comment: I upvoted your anser but some has downvoted. IDK why?

Comment: If you didn't mind modify the code of your page itself to help with the process, you could store a reload count in local storage, and have your page check for that count, decrementing and reloading when the count is above 0.

Comment: The point of this was not for the counter but to check if it works for so many times and holds all values